# How to pattern-match an `Option` in the underlying?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

It says in Scala, pattern-matching will be converted to an invocation of `unapply(...):Option[...]`.

Here I defined an object with `unapply`:

```
object Hello {
  def unapply(s:String): Option[String] = Some(s)
}
```

Then I can use it in pattern-matching:

```
"hello" match {
   case Hello(s) => println(s)
}
```

Actually(maybe) it will be converted to:

```
Hello.unapply("hello") match {
  case Some(s) => println(s)
  case _ =>
}
```

But the `Some` here is also a `case class`, so the `Some.unapply` will be called.

That should be infinite. Which is not possible.

So how do Scala pattern matching the `Option` in the underlying?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is pattern matching in Scala implemented at the bytecode level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754166/how-is-pattern-matching-in-scala-implemented-at-the-bytecode-level)

Answer (score 3):

The result of `unapply` is simply not pattern-matched again. Instead, the methods `isEmpty` and `get` are called. So your example would give:

```
val temp = Hello.unapply("hello")
if (!temp.isEmpty) {
  val s = temp.get
  println(s)
} else {
  throw new MatchError()
}
```

Since 2.11, it is not even necessary to return an `Option`, specifically. Any class with a method `isEmpty: Boolean` and a method `get: A` will do.