# How is the pattern matching for :: implemented?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

For instance,

```
List(1, 2, 3) match {
  case x :: y => (x, y)
}
```

In the code above, pattern matching will automatically find out that any non-empty `List` matches the case `x :: y`. I would like to know, why this happens?

As we all know, there is a `::` method in `List` class. In addition, I find there is a `::` case class in "list.scala":

```
/** A non empty list characterized by a head and a tail.
 *  @param head the first element of the list
 *  @param tl   the list containing the remaining elements of this list after the first one.
 *  @tparam B   the type of the list elements.
 *  @author  Martin Odersky
 *  @version 1.0, 15/07/2003
 *  @since   2.8
 */
@SerialVersionUID(509929039250432923L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

Therefore, we can write `::(1, Nil)` to construct a new `List`. What's more, with the infix notation in Scala, we are able to equivalently write `1 :: Nil` (although it turns out that `Nil.::(1)` will be invoked rather than `::(1, Nil)`, maybe owing to some precedence rules.)

As a result, I guess the case class `::` has something to do with the pattern matching for `::` (say, pattern `x :: y` will be matched by something like `::.unapply`). But I did not find any `unapply` method or companion object for case class `::`.

Could anyone please tell me whether my guess is correct? If not, how is the pattern matching for `::` implemented in Scala?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Obviously, case class as `::` is, a `::.unapply` will be automatically generated for `::`. Thus I can understand that `case x :: y` will match instance of `::` (say, ::(1, 2)). But as we all know, `case x :: y` also matches all instances of type `List`, which is the base class of `::`. Thus I think there might be some special `unapply` were my guess correct.

Comment: `::.unapply` exists because `unapply` is automatically generated for case classes, which `::` is.

Comment: Thanks @m-z, I can understand why `x :: y` will match a instance of `::` case class. But I can't figure out why it also matches a general `List`, which is the base class of case class `::`.

Comment: @m-z, please correct me if I am wrong, I think the automatically generated `D.unapply` only matches instance of `D` but not the base class of D.

Comment: @m-z unapply isn't used for constructor pattern, not that you said so.

Comment: Pattern matching in Scala works by using unapply method of companion object as Extractors. You can read more about them in Part-1 and Part-2 of [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala](http://danielwestheide.com/scala/neophytes.html)

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh No, that's wrong. Also, there's the thing about not answering questions in the comments. :)

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I see the classic guide speaks wrongly, but in the comments he correctly links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754166/how-is-pattern-matching-in-scala-implemented-at-the-bytecode-level but that's not an implementation detail. Arguably this question duplicates that.

Comment: @som-snytt Yes... if we really talk about how it actually works under the hood, but I doubt the OP was talking about under the hood stuff. My guess is that OP is interested in figuring out more flexible or dry patterns. And specifically the semantics of `::` pattern is explained in part-2.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh No, it's *not* implementation detail. The case class has to conform to the expected type of the pattern; the semantics are different. OP asked for implementation but really needed to know just the spec. I don't understand why you say :: is in part 2, because he is showing List.unapplySeq there, which is totally different. (Or please show me where I'm mistaken.)

Comment: @som-snytt You are right. I remember reading about `::` pattern details somewhere and confused the memory with Neophytes guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a constructor pattern:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns

The type (`::`) just has to conform to the pattern type (`List`), and then the "arg" patterns must match.

It looks similar to an extractor pattern, but is different.

edit to show look ma, no extractor:

```
scala> val vs = List(1,2,3)
vs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> vs match { case 1 :: rest => "ok" }
<console>:13: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: List((x: Int forSome x not in 1)), Nil
       vs match { case 1 :: rest => "ok" }
       ^
res0: String = ok

scala> :javap -pv -
[snip]

  public $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=5, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #30                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: putstatic     #32                 // Field MODULE$:L$line4/$read$$iw$$iw$;
         8: aload_0
         9: getstatic     #35                 // Field $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.MODULE$:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$;
        12: invokevirtual #39                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.vs:()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
        15: astore_2
        16: aload_2
        17: instanceof    #41                 // class scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon
        20: ifeq          52
        23: aload_2
        24: checkcast     #41                 // class scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon
        27: astore_3
        28: aload_3
        29: invokevirtual #45                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.head:()Ljava/lang/Object;
        32: invokestatic  #51                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
        35: istore        4
        37: iconst_1
        38: iload         4
        40: if_icmpne     49
        43: ldc           #53                 // String ok
        45: astore_1
        46: goto          64
        49: goto          55
        52: goto          55
        55: new           #55                 // class scala/MatchError
        58: dup
        59: aload_2
        60: invokespecial #58                 // Method scala/MatchError."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        63: athrow
        64: aload_1
        65: putfield      #28                 // Field res0:Ljava/lang/String;
        68: return
[snip]
```

> any non-empty List matches the case x :: y. I would like to know, why
>   this happens?

A non-empty List must be of type `::`. That's what it tests in a constructor pattern. The empty list, `Nil`, is not.

Comment: Thanks @som-snytt. So the existence of :: case class has nothing to do with pattern matching for ::, right?

Comment: It's a ctor pattern because it's a case class. Related confusion: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9795

Comment: Contrast `scala> (1 :: Nil) match { case List(h) => h }` which is an extractor (an unapplySeq).

Comment: That's weird. Why `List(1, 2, 3).isInstanceOf[::[Int]]` gives `true`? I thought `::`(the case class) is a subtype of `List`. (Sorry, I am new to Scala)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not express myself clearly. Thanks to your help, I have already understood the difference between extractor and constructor pattern. But I still have a question that why `List(1, 2, 3).isInstanceOf[::[Int]]` gives `true`.

Comment: I misunderstood you. `List.apply(1)` gives you a `::`. Asking isInstanceOf is not asking `List[Int] <:< ::[Int]`. It's a runtime reflective type check. So a boxed Int i isInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer] for example.